isMobile from useSettings not updating on window resize in Next.js
I am facing an issue with detecting the device type (mobile, tablet, or desktop) in my Next.js application. I'm using the is-mobile npm package to determine the device type and passing this information through settings. However, the isMobile flag does not update correctly when I resize the browser window using Chrome's responsive mode. It remains false even when switching to mobile view.
The implementation is in 3 different files:
In useSetting.ts: I am destructing the settings as code shown below:
import useStore from '~/hooks/useStore';

export const useSettings = () => {
  const [{ settings }] = useStore();

  return settings;
};

The settings is coming through useStore.ts.
In useStore.ts:
import type { Action } from 'react-sweet-state';
import { createHook, createStore } from 'react-sweet-state';

interface iStates {
  settings: iSettings;
}
const actions = {
  setSettings: (settings: Record<any, any>): Action<iStates> => {
    return ({ setState }) => {
      setState({ settings });
    };
  },
};

const store = createStore<iStates, typeof actions>({
  initialState: {
    settings: {},
  },
  actions,
});

export default createHook(store);

While initializing the settings the warning is coming and the warning is :Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'iSettings': isMobile, isPhone, isTablet, isDesktop, and 3 more.
The interface of ISettings:
interface iSettings {
  isMobile: boolean;
  isPhone: boolean;
  isTablet: boolean;
  isDesktop: boolean;
  menu: {
    primary: iPrimaryMenuItem[];
    footer: iPrimaryMenuItem[];
    socials: Array<{ url: string }>;
  };
  lastUpdate: string;
  contactEmails: iContactEmails['emails'];
}

While setting the state in actions the warning is:

Type 'Record<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'iSettings': isMobile, isPhone, isTablet, isDesktop, and 3 more.

Then in _app.tsx: I am update the settings in UseEffect hook and then returning the settings and passing it to Header file
import type { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { PagesProgressBar as ProgressBar } from 'next-nprogress-bar';
import { MantineProvider } from '@mantine/core';
import { APIProvider } from '@vis.gl/react-google-maps';
import { useIsBusiness } from '~/hooks';
import useStore from '~/hooks/useStore';
import { getPrimaryMenu, rawFetch } from '~/utilities';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import md from 'is-mobile';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import '../assets/css/style.css';

App.getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext) => {
  const ua = ctx.req?.headers?.['user-agent'];
  const isMobile = md({ ua, tablet: true });
  const isPhone = md({ ua });
  const isTablet = isMobile && !isPhone;
  const isDesktop = !isMobile;

  const primaryMenu: iMenu = await rawFetch('/menus/v1/menus/primary');
  const socialsMenu: iMenu = await rawFetch('/menus/v1/menus/socials');
  const footerMenu: iMenu = await rawFetch('/menus/v1/menus/footer');
  const contactEmails: iContactEmails = await rawFetch('/acf/v3/options/options/emails');
  const pages = await rawFetch('/wp/v2/pages', { params: { per_page: 1 } });

  return {
    settings: {
      isMobile,
      isPhone,
      isTablet,
      isDesktop,
      menu: {
        primary: getPrimaryMenu(primaryMenu),
        footer: getPrimaryMenu(footerMenu),
        socials: socialsMenu.items?.map(({ url }) => ({ url })),
      },
      lastUpdate: pages?.[0]?.modified,
      contactEmails: contactEmails?.emails,
    },
  };
};
export default function App({ Component, pageProps, settings }: AppProps) {
  const [, { setSettings }] = useStore();
  const isBusiness = useIsBusiness();

  useEffect(() => {
    setSettings(settings);
  }, []);

  return (
    <APIProvider apiKey="AIzaSyDoOlmYovBjVqFi9lZKcuOt0xMSEb15OYc">
      <div className={clsx(isBusiness && 'dark')}>
        <div className="dark:bg-gray-900">
          <MantineProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </MantineProvider>
          <ProgressBar height="4px" color="rgb(230 178 0)" options={{ showSpinner: false }} shallowRouting />
          <Toaster position="top-right" toastOptions={{ style: { borderRadius: '0', background: '#333', color: '#fff' } }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </APIProvider>
  );
}

In _app.tsx there is also warning on default App function:

Property 'settings' does not exist on type 'AppProps'.

I have found some solutions on Chatgpt it give me a solution that I have to extend AppProps but I tried that solution but it is not working
I am newbie in Typescript and Next JS.

Actually the is-mobile library does not work with window size. It works with some meta data like browser type, user agent, and etc.
So changing the window size doesn't cause anything.
This description is at their npm package link:
Check if mobile browser, based on useragent string.
And also about your TypeScript issue, you should extend the AppProps type like this:


// Instead of any, you can write your settings type.
type ExtendedAppProps = AppProps & { settings: any };

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, settings }: ExtendedAppProps)




ok so this code will get rid of the warnings i get but how do i perform resizing because in my mobile screen menu does not appear it there any alternative for this library ?

If you want to show/hide a menu based on the breakpoint (width and height size of the window), it would be better to use CSS media queries instead of installing an external library.

where should i write CSS and how as I told you i am a beginner in next so didn't really know it's folder structure if you could help me guide through it that would be appreciated

You can follow the instructions here: https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles
And also here is a guide to CSS media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#creating_complex_media_queries
